# Asp net core 2.1 RC with Npgsql 2.1 unable to scaffold existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Trying to scaffold an Existing Database

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=localhost;Database=mydatabase;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

throws this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure.Internal.INpgsqlOptions'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlTypeMappingSource'.

Current Setup:

- Asp.Net Core 2.1 RC
- EntityFrameworkCore 2.1
- Npgsql 2.1 RC

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have these packages installed, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL & Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design

Comment: Yes i have them installed